# Does a parked car lie in the street, or sit in the street, or stand in the street?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Does a parked car

> **lie** in the street

or

> **sit** in the street

or

> **stand** in the street

?

Is there a rule to determine which verb to use with a specific noun, when the noun describes a thing – like a ball – which cannot have different positions, contrary to a human being for instance?

Comment: I think the one example is not very helpful. However, by comparing cars, ships, balls, pyramids, poles, plates, books, bicycles, computers, couches, beds, chairs, rockets, blankets etc. there might pop up _some_ rule.

Comment: @Keepthesemind Would it be fair to say that for inanimate objects "lying" and "standing" are forms of sitting?

Comment: In general, "lie" would not be used.  "Sit" implies that the vehicle is parked in a normal fashion, while "stand" implies that the vehicle is sitting ready for immediate use (possibly with the engine running).  To a large extent these "rules" are idiomatic, though, and not traceable to some sort of "logic".

Comment: Parked cars park.  Nobody I know ever says "My car lies/sits/stands in the street."  They say "My car is parked in the street", or "parked on 3rd avenue".

Comment: Use whatever term you prefer.  Some people will love your choice, others will hate it.

Comment: These are all metaphors of human body posture - _lie, sit, stand_ all refer to the body. So pick one and stick with it (though people don't usually notice inconsistencies). _Lie_ means they're out of order ("asleep" or "wounded"); _stand_ means they're ready for business, like outside a bank; _sit_ means they're being stored, possibly in a parking place with others.

Answer (score 3):

**A parked car usually *stands***.

The only time it ***lies*** is if it is not in an upright position and is e.g. *lying in a ditch*, or *lying on its side/upside down in the road*.

As for ***sitting***. how exactly would it do that?

**Edit 1 June 2023** Just thinking about this again - seven years on - and having read the comments, I think that the use of *standing*, would, in Britain, suggest something unusual about the parked cars in question. If they were perfectly regular cars in a car park, one would say simply - "there are seven cars in the car park". I would only say "there were seven cars standing in the car park" if perhaps for some obvious reason there should not have been any e.g. it was a church car park at 3.00am.

Cars don't usually *sit* in a car park - but sometimes you do hear of a car "sitting in the drive (of a house)".

I have not really changed my mind about *lying*. It is something a car rarely does except when it has skidded off the road into a ditch.

As regards *in the street*, in Britain I think we would only rarely say a car was "standing" in the street, if it was merely parked there. "Standing" might suggest it was not properly parked at the side of the road, but just standing in the way of traffic and causing an obstruction.

**Edit** One commenter has produced an example, from American fiction, of a car *sitting*. My own belief is that this would be rare in Britain, but I am ready to be proved wrong. However I have now changed my assertion from *a car always stands* to *a car usually stands*.

Comment: Why standing instead of sitting?

Comment: This only answers the title question, not the (other) "body question".

Comment: In the Northeast US (and possibly elsewhere) ["standing"](http://newyorkparkingticket.com/parking-law-do-you-know-the-difference-between-parking-standing/) has a very specific meaning.  A car is standing when it is stopped for the purposes of loading or unloading passengers or cargo.  If a car is stopped and no loading or unloading is happening, the car is said to be "parked."

Comment: I agree with the bit about "lying" but inanimate things "sit" all the time.  Sitting doesn't mean you're on your butt in a chair necessarily.  It just means that you are located in a place for a time.  You are SITuated if you will.  That is what I always thought at least.

Comment: @Lumberjack- and I think it needs to be running with the driver behind the wheel.

Comment: A parked car could very well be sitting in front of the suspect's house.

Comment: @Lumberjack Let's see what my compatriots say when they wake up. But in Britain I don't think we talk about a car *sitting*. If someone was inside we might say, referring to the occupant *He's sitting in the car park*. But I don't believe a car *sits*, but I could be wrong.

Comment: *The green-and- white Ford was **sitting** in the driveway.*  [source](https://books.google.com/books?id=0u6ALeRMZ28C&pg=PA45&dq=%22sitting+in+the+driveway%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwie56r8so7NAhWGRiYKHd5vDrgQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22sitting%20in%20the%20driveway%22&f=false).  There are about 100 other examples that Ngram found.

Comment: @HotLicks John Dunning is an American writer. You may find it more difficult to find an example of "a car sitting" in British fiction. But I'm not saying it is impossible.

Comment: Found a [book by Gayle Ramage](https://books.google.com/books?id=7sF8BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT10&dq=%22sitting+in+the+car+park%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjbg53b847NAhUPV1IKHXPnCRwQ6AEIKTAC#v=onepage&q=%22sitting%20in%20the%20car%20park%22&f=false), but Google won't let me access it properly to give a good link here. *There were many empty vehicles sitting in the car park.*  (Could probably find more, but "driveway" of course doesn't work for British books.)

Comment: @HotLicks I couldn't actually find it from that link, but ok I concede the argument to you. What would you like me to do? Delete my answer?

Comment: Each of _sit, stand_ and _lie_ is used as a pretty transparent metaphor (and this assumes that the original sense applied to stative human posture). 'Be [situated/located]' are synonyms. But not all S + V pairings are equally idiomatic, and as you say, some such pairings inform a more exact relationship between the subject referent and its surroundings.

Answer (score 0):

'Stands' would be normal, but any of the others can also be used.

'Sits' gets [fairly frequent usage](https://www.google.com/?ion=1&espv=2#q=%22car%20sits%20on%20the%20street%22). I'm not sure if 'sits' indicates anything different from 'stands' here.

'Lies' would tend to indicate something the matter with the car. A wreck of a car would lie on the street, and maybe lesser broken down cars.

Comment: This only answers the title question, not the (other) "body question".

Answer (score 0):

In the example above, the word "parked" describes the position along with what kind of car. A speeding car would not be standing, lying, sitting or parking. If I had to use this in a sentence I would re-word to " A car was parked in the street" and not apply sitting, lying or standing. As for a "ball" you would not say "A bouncing ball was lying in the street". But you could say "A ball was lying in the street".

Answer (score 0):

None of these sound natural, either the verb or the preposition.

Here are examples of idiomatic (natural sounding) English:

> The car is parked.
>
> The car is parked in the driveway.
>
> The car is parked on the street.
>
> The car is parked next to the fire hydrant.
>
> The car is standing in the 'no standing' zone.
>
> The parked car is in the driveway.
>
> The speeding car is on the street.
>
> That other car is parked on the shoulder of the highway.
>
> The van is at the stoplight right now.

The rule for the verb for car is 'stand' or 'park', whatever the adjective modifying car is. 'Lying' (or 'laying') and 'sitting' don't work.

The rule for the preposition depends on the object of the preposition (and intention/restrictions on the object).

There are lots of options among these but they can be restricted by pragmatics of the physical situation. A ball can lie on the field or be in the air or next to the wall but not at the wall.

Prepositions are difficult in English because they are so slippery, with multiple overlapping meanings. You say 'on the ceiling' if something is pressed up against the ceiling, even though literally 'on' seems to imply above. The lesson is to not be too literal.

Comment: How about "I can see his car sitting in the driveway"?  That would be perfectly idiomatic in the US.

Comment: @HotLicks That sounds fine but is not the first thing I would come up with. "The car is in the street" is off, or rather fits the situation where the asphalt has melted and the car has sunk into the street.

Answer (score 0):

A car can be described as doing any of those things and examples are easily come by, here are a few from Google Books:

> 2010 Struggling With the Spirit: Stories of Inspiration - Page 198. D.
> Adair *The car **sat** outside the house for a few moments as Aunt Roths
> and Bob watched the silhouettes of Ralph and his pets through the back
> lit curtain.*
>
> 2010 My Family and Other Strangers: Adventures in Family History,
> Jeremy Hardy *The car **sat** outside the house in her cul de sac, and on
> the Monday morning, we got in it and she drove me to the airport.*
>
> 2009 The World of Jack Dennison-detective - Page 170 Albert E. Farrar
> *The car **lay** on its side with it's driver on the side closest to the ground.*
>
> 2011 And the Land Lay Still James Robertson *The bullet that lodged in
> his brain could not have been fired from some distance away and hit
> him where it did because of the angle at which the car **lay**.*
>
> 2013 Paths to Sunset - Page 22 Craig Brown *From where the car **stood**,
> by craning his neck, he could just make out the door he had come
> through.*
>
> 1908 The Wind in the Willows - Page 69 Kenneth Grahame *The car **stood** in the middle of the yard, quite unattended, the stable-helps and other hangers-on being all at their dinner.*

> Is there a rule to determine which verb to use with a specific noun, when the noun describes a thing – like a ball – which cannot have different positions, contrary to a human being for instance?

No. In general terms you are wasting your time if you try to find "rules" in English. English, like all other languages is filled with exceptions.

**In the case of a car**,

**Lie** is usually ("usually does not mean "always") used to mean that the car is not upright;

**Stand** is usually ("usually does not mean "always") used to mean that the car's position is emphasised.

**Sit** usually ("usually does not mean "always") used to mean that the car is waiting for something to happen to it.

Other nouns will/may have other nuances attached to their verbs - obviously, nobody is going to list every verb and every noun for you.

Comment: References! Upvote. / 'Lie' often means that the car's situation is somehow compromised ... perhaps overturned, perhaps clapped out and in a field. // 'Sit' would probably be used if the car was up to its floor in a stream.

Comment: I still believe in rules, even for English.  Parked, versus permanently parked.  And, only one set may be right.